# Import Data Permission Denied

Tags: mysql

My permission? isn't working. I have MySQL at home, and it works great, this is at work and just got the default developer version downloaded to my Windows pc. When I try to upload a CSV that was converted from an Excel file, it denies it. GR. I've tried so many things to work around. Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4z5L.png)

```
12: 10:35 Restoring C: Lab Roster & Preferences. csv
Running: mysql.exe —host=127.0.O.1 —user=svazquez —port=3306 —default-character-set=utf —comments —
database=sarav < Lab Roster & Preferences.csv•
mysql: Error reading fie '<unopen fd>' (OS errno 13 - Perrnission denied)
Operation faied wifr exitcode 1
12: 10:35 Import of C: usershsfreobaldDocuments\Tech Lab Roster & Preferences.csv has fir-ished 1 errors
```

Here is the pic of my error. I might need access to more of my company's server? But I don't even know what access to ask for.

When I tried to just ImportFile, it told me that the "secure_file_priv" was on, so it couldn't complete the task.

Comment: Text is so much clearer than a picture, (sorry, but my OCR software is not better than this...)

Comment: You are trying to connect to a server on the same computer (127.0.0.1).  If this is a company server, then you need to specify the IP address of the server computer.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your link to your 'Import Progress' report indicates path to data with multiple 'back slashes' in the string.   We do not normally see multiple consecutive back or forward slashes in any path to data.

Comment: You cannot load CSV file by this way. The method which you use accepts a dump (.SQL file) - text file with valid SQL queries, not the file with CSV data.

Comment: thanks everyone. I will ruminate on these responses. For now I did a workaround and built the tables in MySQL manually